# Selenium+Python chrome webdriver popup problem

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

When I tried to login an internal website, I got a problem to get the elements.
The window screenshot is as blow,It’s neither an iframe nor a div nor others. Even the html was not loaded.

[image]

How can I enter the id and password automatically?
My environment:
Win10 + Chrome + python3.7

my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import chromedriver_binary
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options = chrome_options)
driver.get('..xxx.aspx')  ##driver stoped to wait enter the id and password,I can't use driver.find_element to locate the elements.
driver.maximize_window()
```

Comment: I think there was a built in function to handle popups, but you can try to go "dummy way" on it and just program key's down :D

Comment: http://userid:password@ttt.com!